# converting NSString to NSURL from a plist file

Tags: nsstring, plist, nsurl

I've been trying to get a string from a plist file into a NSURL for webview. 
Either i get 'nil' for the returned value, or nothing (no error in console)

I know something's wrong with this code, but i can't pinpoint it where.

```
   NSString *filePath = @"/path/to/Info.plist";
   NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

   NSString *value;
   value = [plistDict objectForKey:@"Link"];
   NSString *webStringURL = [value stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];
   [self loadURL:URL];
   [self setURLToLoad:nil];
```

Where did i mess up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    NSString *filePath = @"/path/to/Info.plist";
   NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

   NSString *urlString = [plistDict objectForKey:@"Link"];

   NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
   [self loadURL:URL];
```

For your better understanding refer to this site:

http://iphonesdevsdk.blogspot.com/2011/04/plist.html

It may help you in using plist in easy way.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the tip. I had used this code (+variations of it) before, but somehow it didn't work. Now i know why. You have to use http:// in front of the 'www' link, or else nothing will load up. This is the problem i had for a few days now. To think that webview doesn't use a link without the http header, heh.